# Visualforce Page useful information

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

I am new into apex development and I need to learn as much as I can. The best way for me to do so is if i can lay my hands on apex examples or just detailed explained code.
So I would love if the community share some links that will be useful for me and for the future visitors of this post, or link me other questions (on this website) that are answered previously and you think they might be useful.

Beside all the documentations that I've encountered this is far more useful link that i found:
http://salesforce-stuff.blogspot.com/

Please share I need to learn,

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Darko,
                     Its great you want to grow yourself while learning new things. If you want to learn more about Apex, Visual force then you follow these links http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/
and download apex workbook and visual force workbook and study these books. After that you follow blogs related to sales force . There are many blogs like http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/ and you can join sales force success community and developer form there are a lot of to learn.If you need more then let me know.
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat